# How do I create a new column and move data to it with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //omitted for brevity
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //omitted for brevity
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

enum Status
{
    Active,
    Inactive,
    NoState,
}
```

Person is a database table with data. Due to new requirement I would like to remove IsActive and have a Status enum. I would also like to move the data from IsActive column to Status column without losing it. I'm using EF Code First. How do I go about it?

Comment: are you using migrations?  if so it would simply be a case of adding the new column, running some sql, and then dropping the old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this. The steps I followed are as follows;

1. Scaffold an Add-Migration AlterStatusEnum through package manager console.
2. In the Up method of the generated partial class, change the 
   **AddColumn("dbo.Person","Status", c => c.Int(nullable:false));**
   to
   **RenameColumn("dbo.Person", "IsActive", "Status");**
3. Add an alter statement 
   **AlterColumn("dbo.Person", "Status", c => c.Int(nullable: false));**
   this got the job done.

Sample code

```
public partial class AlterStatusEnum : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameColumn("dbo.Person", "IsActive", "Status");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Person", "Status", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        // Removed for brevity
    }
}
```

In a nutshell all am doing is renaming the existing column and altering its datatype.